# Как получить ссылку на скачивание video?

Tags: javascript, php, html, веб-программирование

Ниже прилагаю скрин страницы с аудио из ВКонтакте. Как извлечь ссылку на скачивание аудио / видео из тега video (без непосредственного нажатия на "..."->"Скачать"). Желательно через JavaScript. Или как-нибудь через php...
[image: скрин]
[ссылка на аудио](https://cs3-3v4.vkuseraudio.net/p3/75e94a9681598a.mp3?extra=Mkjq8dWLTLFYsbp88teO-BNljQVAAEy-tYhY-uQJuVw_rlPsaYQsi21Q4voEMXnH5-gDk9tUV1d4aZ3mU0Cr1-T6dVMPedmaHUc36mwXZXgV8zwCPeguNVgFMcM-BgAu8zTG2OKov7mAb1qVKKR7XUc30Q)

Comment: Ну просто по этой ссылке скачайте. Браузер отображает тег img, video, audio для соответственых файлов, чтоб их проиграть

Comment: @ДавидМанжула, хорошо. Ещё вопрос, не подскажете, как с помощью javascript запустить процесс скачивания этого файла?

Comment: @ДавидМанжула, вот пример кода, что нужно исправить?
let link = document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute('href', 'https://cs3-1v4.vkuseraudio.net/p4/d79cf514b63ee4.mp3');
link.setAttribute('download', '');
window.onload = link.click();

Comment: Во-первых, вы не указали протокол. Нужно было указать `link.setAttribute('href', 'https://cs3-1v4.vkuseraudio.net/p4/d79cf514b63ee4.mp3')`

Comment: Во вторых, на сколько я понимаю, браузеры блокируют атрбут download для запросов между разными доменами. То есть со своего сайта нельзя будет скачать.